# How to increase Height and Width of Crosstab Cell in Crystal report dynamically according to text size?

Tags: crystal-reports

How to increase Height and Width of Crosstab Cells in Crystal report dynamically according to text size. I have already checked the "Can grow" property to true for individual cells but have no change.
I am new in crystal reports. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think you can.  You only get to set the height and width of one crosstab cell at design time.  You may have to consider a different approach that 'simulates' different column widths in the crosstab.